# Underwater Shader Animation Help

Tags: opengl, shaders, glsl, fragment-shader

I found an underwater (distort) effect and I got it to work but somehow I cannot make it animate given the offset here:

Fragment Shader code:

```
uniform sampler2D fbo_texture;
uniform float offset;
varying vec2 f_texcoord;

void main(void) {
  vec2 texcoord = f_texcoord;
  texcoord.x += sin(texcoord.y * 4*2*3.14159 + offset) / 100;
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(fbo_texture, texcoord);
}
```

Original Source [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Post-Processing#A_first_effect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out by looking other shader examples and hopefully it will benefit others. elapsedTime can be added to the computation or offset and will animate the effect, some use sin/cos as well..

```
uniform float elapsedTime;
```